# How to add Delimiter inside foreach of Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I need to add comma Delimiter for below observable array

`this.Filter = ko.observableArray([{ "Key": "1", "Value": "a" }, { "Key": "2", "Value": "b"     }, { "Key": "3", "Value": "c" }]);`

I need to show above array like a,b,c

```
<td data-bind="foreach: Filter">
   <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
</td>
```

But the value is showing like a b c

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
<td data-bind="foreach: Filter">
   <!-- ko if: $index() > 0 -->,<!-- /ko -->
   <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this put a `,` after the last entry? i.e. `a,b,c,`?

Comment: No, it puts the , before the value if index > 0

Answer (score 13):

You can do this:

```
<td data-bind="foreach: Filter">
    <!--ko if: $index() != 0-->,<!--/ko-->
   <span data-bind="text: Value"></span>
</td>
```

But it is better to have computed that will concatenate arrays values:

```
self.Filter2 = ko.computed(function (){
    var result = "";
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Filter(), function(item){
        if (!result){
            result = item.Value;
        }
        else{
            result = result + ', ' + item.Value;
        }
    });
    return result;
});
```

Here is fiddle with both variants: http://jsfiddle.net/XrB7z/

Comment: The computed is only useful if you are just displaying the text....   if you need to do further KO processing with the items then that won't work.

Answer (score 5):

**The modern CSS way**

Same markup + class:

```
<td data-bind="foreach: Filter" class="comma-separated">
   <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.comma-separated {
  display: flex;
}

.comma-separated > span + span:before {
  content: ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a computed is probably the best solution.

```
this.filterAsString = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Filter(), function(item) {
        return item.Value;
    }).join(', ');
}, this);
```

HTML:

```
<td data-bind="text: filterAsString"></td>
```

Comment: This depends on how purely MVVM you wanna be. Some dev's consider the comma to be part of the layout (View) and not the behavior (ViewModel). But I'm not saying its wrong :P